# Explanation of Proof of Heine-Borel

Tags: proof-explanation, compactness

I'm confused by the proof of Heine-Borel. The proof I'm referring to is the following:

Assume that there is a closed and bounded set $X$ of size $s$ which isn't compact. Then we can split $X$ into two sets and at least one of the sets is not covered by a finite subcover. WLOG we can say one of the sets (call it $X_1$) is not covered by a finite subcover. We can continue the subdivision of $X_1$ and so on, getting a sequence of sets $\{X, X_1, X_2, X_3, ...\}$, and we know by the nested interval theorem that this sequence contains a point, say $x_0$. Then we can take the open set containing $x_0$, call it $C$ and since the sequence of sets leads to arbitrarily small sets, we eventually end up with some set $X_n$ of arbitrarily small size which is covered by $C$. Contradiction, therefore $X$ is compact.

To me, this seems to be saying something about the sum of open sets - I'm envisioning this method of subdivision saying that $\sum_n{(b-a)/2^n} = b-a$, and you don't need $n$ to go to infinity because there's an open set around $b$ with a fixed radius. However, in my mind that only holds true if you assume only one of the sets in the subdivision is not covered by a finite subcover - what if both of the sets in the subdivision is assumed to not be covered by a finite subcover at every single point? Then wouldn't there be a possibly infinite amount of points $x_0, x_1...$ (and therefore an infinite subcover). This could hold true if the open sets around the various points $x_0, x_1...$ could have increasingly smaller and smaller radii? If the radii decreased faster than exponentially then why wouldn't the number of subdivisions (and thus, covers) go to infinity as well?

Essentially I can see how you can take care of one sequence with this proof method, but I don't see how you can take care of an exponentially growing amount of sequences.

Comment: The proof above has some gaps. But none concern the question you ask. When you say "This is saing something about the sum of open sets", there itself you have an issue in understanding the argument. Where do you see a sum of open sets here?(Kindly bear with me, I am only trying to get to the root of your issue, since for me the questions you ask seem mildly tangential to the argument)

Comment: The way that I am envisioning this in my head is that if the set X is [0,1] is that there is an open set covering [0, 1/2], then one covering [1/2, 1/2+1/4], and then one containing [1/2+1/4, 1/2+1/4+1/8], and so on. The proof is saying something like the reason that this is not an infinite number of sets is because there is some open cover around [1], say [1-x, 1+y], so we can reach [1-x] in a finite number of steps. It's not necessarily about the sum of open sets, more of the convergence of a sequence. I'm reading more about the monotone convergence theorem among other things, which helps

Comment: But the issue I had was that I understood how it worked for a simple sequence like [0, 1/2, 1/2+1/4, 1/2+1/4+1/8...] but I wasn't sure how it worked for more complex sequences.

Comment: It turns out this was my intuition, but I didn't know how to deal with case 4! https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/an-analysis-of-the-first-proofs-of-the-heine-borel-theorem-borels-proof

Comment: "The set $X$ is [0,1] is that there is an open set covering $[0,\frac 12]$" : no, no , this is not correct at all! Do you understand the following statement : "If $X$ cannot be covered by a finite subcover, then regardless of how you break $X$ into $X_1$ and $X_2$, one of the pieces will also not have a finite subcover"? You are talking of $[0,\frac 12]$ being covered  by a full open set, then $[0,\frac 12 + \frac 14]$ etc. , but these sets should be getting smaller, you are making them bigger, I don't get what is going on. Also, where is dominated convergence coming in?

Comment: The article which you read is so heavily worded, I must put some physical effort into reading it. I will try.

Comment: Don't worry I understand it better now! I meant [0, 1/2] and [1/2, 1/2+1/4], not [0, 1/2+1/4]. Thanks for your help ( :

Comment: Or no, pardon me. Do you not understand Borel's argument in the link you sent me?

Comment: I understand it now. I was trying to apply his type of constructive argument to the subdivision proof in the original post which is why I was failing. thanks again for your help

Comment: Sure, you are welcome.